# Collection view and composite view in backbone.js

Tags: marionette

Can we use regions inside collection view and composite view in backbone.js?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no. Only `LayoutView` has support for regions. If you tell me more about your usecase, preferably in the form a jsfiddle, I'd try to to give you code sample to address your usecase.

Comment: it's not built in, but you could always create your own region instances inside your render method. i agree, though, that the use case should be evaluated and the problem might have a better solution